# Adding zest libraries to Eclipse 4 app

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef, e4, zest

I am new to both Zest and Eclipse e4 development. My aim for the moment is to build a simple app and in one of its views to visualize a graph using Zest. So I am following [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html) tutorial and I ended up with a simple working app consisting of one main window split in 3 parts.

Now I want to display a graph in one of the parts. In order to do that I have downloaded the whole GEF framework into my Eclipse from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/updates/index.php) using the "Install New Software" feature of Eclipse. So far so good.

Next I try to add the following dependencies to the Required-plugins section of the manifest file: `org.eclipse.zest.core` and `org.eclipse.zest.layouts`

Upon running the project I end up with

> No Application ID found

When I remove them everything is working as usual. Do you guys have any idea how I can fix this?

This is the error message:

```
!SESSION 2013-11-18 18:38:56.285 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_21
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.andrey.e4.rcp.todo.product -clearPersistedState
Command-line arguments:  -product com.andrey.e4.rcp.todo.product -data     C:\Users\Andrez\Desktop\projects/../runtime-com.andrey.e4.rcp.todo.product -dev file:C:/Users/Andrez/Desktop/projects/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/com.andrey.e4.rcp.todo.product/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -consoleLog -clearPersistedState

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.app 0 0 2013-11-18 18:38:57.835
!MESSAGE Product com.andrey.e4.rcp.todo.product could not be found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-11-18 18:38:57.890
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-11-18 18:38:57.891
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:../../projects/com.andrey.e4.rcp.todo/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.andrey.e4.rcp.todo 2 0 2013-11-18 18:38:57.891
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.zest.layouts_1.1.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.andrey.e4.rcp.todo 2 0 2013-11-18 18:38:57.891
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.zest.core_1.5.0.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-11-18 18:38:57.900
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-11-18 18:38:57.901
!MESSAGE Bundle com.andrey.e4.rcp.todo_1.0.0.qualifier [70] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.andrey.e4.rcp.todo 2 0 2013-11-18 18:38:57.901
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.zest.core_1.5.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.andrey.e4.rcp.todo 2 0 2013-11-18 18:38:57.901
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.zest.layouts_1.1.0.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-11-18 18:38:57.932
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-11-18 18:38:57.932
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:../../projects/com.andrey.e4.rcp.todo/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.andrey.e4.rcp.todo 2 0 2013-11-18 18:38:57.933
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.zest.layouts_1.1.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.andrey.e4.rcp.todo 2 0 2013-11-18 18:38:57.933
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.zest.core_1.5.0.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-11-18 18:38:57.939
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-11-18 18:38:57.939
!MESSAGE Bundle com.andrey.e4.rcp.todo_1.0.0.qualifier [70] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.andrey.e4.rcp.todo 2 0 2013-11-18 18:38:57.939
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.zest.core_1.5.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.andrey.e4.rcp.todo 2 0 2013-11-18 18:38:57.940
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.zest.layouts_1.1.0.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-11-18 18:38:57.946
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: No application id has been found.
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:242)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I'd try is clicking the 'Add required Plug-ins' button in the 'Plug-ins' tab of your Run Configuration. You could also try running a different product in the 'Main' tab of the run configuration.

Comment: This is the correct answer, I ran into the exact same problem as the original poster and as you say, the problem is that the run configuration does not include all of the required plugins.