# Adding GEF4's Zest to Eclipse 4 RCP Application - Dependency nightmare

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef

I am trying to create an Eclipse RCP application which uses GEF4's Zest.

What works OK:

I have downloaded Eclipse Neon last week and have been playing with it to do this. I have found a few GEF4 Zest examples online and I am able to run them in Eclipse using the simple "Run As > Java Application" option after adding a bunch of dependencies. In addition, I have created and successfully run a simple RCP application using the "Eclipse 4 RCP Application" wizard. So far so good.

What does not work and I need help with:

I am trying to add a simple single line of code from the GEF4 Zest sample code to this fresh "Eclipse 4 RCP Application":

...
ZestContentViewer viewer = new ZestContentViewer(null);
...

I do have the following import as well:
import org.eclipse.gef4.zest.fx.jface.ZestContentViewer;

It should be easy given I have already run this successfully by adding those dependencies manually to the first simple Java App.

However, I have spent the last three days trying to resolve the dependencies just to run this one line of code. I virtually and practically have spent three days and I am getting no where.

I have tried many possible fixes as I am going to mention below but the errors all end up being of the following:

Error type 1: A missing org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control class.
Error type 2: Two bundles trying to load the same class.
Error type 3: One of com.google.inject or similar classes not being found.
and there are a few other types of errors which I have encountered.

Note that in all cases I do compile the application with no errors.
It's only at run-time when everything breaks apart.

What I have tried which did not help:

1) Create a separate bundle from those jar files and export them.
2) Play with Run Configurations to make sure the required plugins are loaded.
3) Adding "Required Plug-ins" to the MANIFEST.MF
4) Importing the jar files under the /lib/ in the project
5) Extracting all the jar file .class files and importing them into the project

And referring to lots of questions and answers including the following:

[Adding zest libraries to Eclipse 4 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055182/adding-zest-libraries-to-eclipse-4-app)

Unfortunately none of these have helped.

Please give me some suggestions or if possible a "ready to use" empty project template which fixes this "GEF4 Zest in RCP" problem which I can modify and make work on my local machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to setup an application with GEF Zest (or GEF4 Zest), you can follow the instructions given at [github](https://github.com/eclipse/gef#getting-started-with-the-framework-components-adopters).

If you still run into errors/problems after following these instructions, feel free to report them here and we will find a solution.

Comment: Thanks. I eventually figured it out by doing lots of searches before seeing your response. The most complicated parts, if one's not familiar with Eclipse and GEF, are getting the dependencies (the required JAR files) right and the part where you have to add
"-Dosgi.framework.extensions=org.eclipse.fx.osgi" to "VM arguments". I kept trying to add this "fx.osgi" package to my dependencies which of course didn't have happy results.
But I can see you've added that to the README file on your link which means you're not missing out the most important details :)